# insert via checkbox

Tags: php, sql, checkbox, insert

I'm trying to insert via checkbox, but it saves only one record, suppose in the table I've got 10 records, it saves only the 10th one.  I think there is a problem in the for each. Can anyone help me?

```
<form id="assign" name="assign" method="post" action="assign_individual_exec.php">

    <tr><td class="style3">Select course name:</td>
    <td><select name="name" class="principal2"><?php select_coursename(); ?></select></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="style3"> Start Date</td>
<td><input type="date" name="sdate" ></td><td><script language="JavaScript">
    new tcal ({
        'formname': 'assign',

        'controlname': 'sdate'
    });

    </script></td></tr>



<?php

include('member_table.php');
?>

    <tr>
      <div align="right"class="lien">

        <td><input type="submit" name="individual" value="assign to individual"  />
```

**member_table.php**

```
<?php


$member_id = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];

   $first= mysql_query("select userid from dept_user where lead_id=$member_id");

echo "<table border='1' id=coursetable class=coursetable>
<tr>
<th>first name</th>
<th>last name</th>
<th>dept name</th>
<th>title</th>
<th>rolename</th>
<th>leader first name</th>
<th>leader last name</th>
</tr>";

 while($res = mysql_fetch_array($first)){

$user1 = $res['userid'];


$display= mysql_query("Select user.firstname, user.lastname, department.dept_name, job_title.title, role.rolename, user.userid From user Inner Join  dept_user On user.userid = dept_user.userid Inner Join  department On department.dept_id = dept_user.dept_id Inner Join  job_title On job_title.title_id = user.titleid Inner Join  role On role.roleid = user.roleid Where user.userid = $user1 "); 




$leader = mysql_query("Select firstname , lastname From user Inner Join  dept_user On user.userid = dept_user.lead_id  Where dept_user.lead_id =$member_id");

while(($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($display)) and ($lead = mysql_fetch_array($leader)))

  {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row1['firstname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row1['lastname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row1['dept_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row1['title'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>"  . $row1['rolename'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>"  . $lead['firstname'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>"  . $lead['lastname'] . "</td>";
echo  "<td>" .'<input type="checkbox" name="userid" value='.$row1['userid'].'>'."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

  }

 if ($user1 !== 0){

 $second = mysql_query("select userid from dept_user where lead_id=$user1");

 while($res1 = mysql_fetch_array($second)){

 $user2= $res1['userid'];



if($user2 !==0) {



   $display2 = mysql_query("Select user.firstname, user.lastname, department.dept_name, job_title.title, role.rolename, user.userid From user Inner Join  dept_user On user.userid = dept_user.userid Inner Join  department On department.dept_id = dept_user.dept_id Inner Join  job_title On job_title.title_id = user.titleid Inner Join  role On role.roleid = user.roleid Where user.userid = $user2 "); 


   $leader1= mysql_query("Select firstname , lastname From user Inner Join  dept_user On user.userid = dept_user.lead_id  Where dept_user.lead_id = $user1");

while(($res1 = mysql_fetch_array($display2))  and ($lead1 = mysql_fetch_array($leader1)))

  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $res1['firstname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $res1['lastname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $res1['dept_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $res1['title'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>"  . $res1['rolename'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>"  . $lead1['firstname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>"  . $lead1['lastname'] . "</td>";
echo  "<td>" .'<input type="checkbox" name="userid" value='.$res1['userid'].'>'."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }

    if ($user2 !== 0){

    $third = mysql_query("select userid from dept_user where lead_id=$user2");

while($res2 = mysql_fetch_array($third)) {

 $user3 = $res2['userid'];

 echo "<br/>";

 if ($user3 !== 0){


 $display3 = mysql_query("Select user.firstname, user.lastname, department.dept_name, job_title.title, role.rolename, user.userid From user Inner Join  dept_user On user.userid = dept_user.userid Inner Join  department On department.dept_id = dept_user.dept_id Inner Join  job_title On job_title.title_id = user.titleid Inner Join  role On role.roleid = user.roleid Where user.userid = $user3"); 

    $leader2 = mysql_query("Select firstname, lastname From user Inner Join  dept_user On user.userid = dept_user.lead_id  Where dept_user.lead_id = $user2");

while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($display3)) and ($lead2 = mysql_fetch_array($leader2)))


  {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['dept_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>"  . $row['rolename'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>"  . $lead2['firstname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>"  . $lead2['lastname'] . "</td>";
echo  "<td>" .'<input type="checkbox" name="userid" value='.$row['userid'].'>'."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }

}
    }
}
}
}

}
}
echo"</table>";
?>
```

**assign_training_exec.php**

```
<?php
include('include.php'); 
    include('config.php');
    require_once('auth.php');
    session_start();


$user[]= clean($_POST['userid']);
    $name = clean($_POST['name']);
    $date = clean($_POST['sdate']);
$month = substr($date, 0 ,2);
 $day= substr($date, 3, -5); 
$yr = substr($date, 6); 
$dash = "-";
$date_str = ($yr.$dash.$month.$dash.$day);


$m_name = $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];

   foreach ($user as $user_array){
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO course_detail(userid, course_id, date_assign, owner) VALUES('$user_array','$name','$date_str', '$m_name')"; 
    $insert = mysql_query($insert_query); 
}



    if($insert_buffer) {

                exit();
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }

?>
```

Comment: 1. I don't see a question here.

Comment: That's great!  What's the question?

Comment: 2. You should really fix the formatting issues.

Comment: Also, I don't see a checkbox anywhere?

Comment: inotsurewhattheproblemis,areyoutryingtogetacheckboxforall10itemsorjustone.Theformattingisveryhardtoread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line in *member_table.php* :

(current line :)

```
echo  "<td>" .'<input type="checkbox" name="userid" value='.$row1['userid'].'>'
```

change to :

```
echo  "<td>" .'<input type="checkbox" name="userid[]" value='.$row1['userid'].'>'
```

The [] in the input's name attribute enable to iterate through it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this assigns the result of the clean() to the new end element of the array
// $user[] = clean($_POST['userid']);
// 
// should be more like:
$user = array_clean($_POST['userid']);
```

I'm not familiar with your clean(), but you'll need to use an array-returning function, instead of a single value. The clean() your using may work on both arrays and scalars, but if not, try the one below:

```
function array_clean( $input_array ) {
   $clean_array = new array();
   if( !is_array($input_array) ) {
    $clean_array[] = clean($input_array);
    return $clean_array;
   }
   foreach( $input_array as $key => $value ) {
      $clean_array[$key] = clean($value);
   }
    return $clean_array;
}
```

Also, what Rodolphe pointed out, you need to append [] on the fields you want to be returned as an array (thanks for noting, Rodolphe)...

```
while( /*...*/ ) {
   //...
   echo  "<td>" .'<input type="checkbox" name="userid[]" value='.$row1['userid'].'>'."</td>";
   //...
}
enter code here
```

Comment: ya i've tried doing it like this, but when execute, get this error

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\tracker\assign_individual_exec.php on line 46

Comment: One of two things: 1) try the new fix from Rudolphe, and maybe 2) you'll have to write your own function like array_clean(), because that clean function may not be for arrays. I've edited and all that's in this answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I can't make anything from your text, but the most common error is probably the name of the checkboxes. Add "[]" to their name and PHP will automagically convert it into an array with all checked values.

Change

```
<input type="checkbox" name="the_name">
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="the_name[]">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the array exists. If none of the checkboxes checked, no entry will exist in the $_POST-array.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you.. i've tried to apply the array on the name earlier before but did not work. this time i've removed the clean function. it works well and save in the database. but providing error msg "query failed". this can be fixed, just the last code.. thx guys..

Comment: if($insert_buffer) {
 needed to change the variable from $inser_buffer to $insert. its gud now